# _this2.props.tonPress is not a function in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native

I have the following error `"_this2.props.tonPress is not a function"` in my code, I try to solve it but I don't now where is the problem in my code, and I can't read props, can I have some help please:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {TouchableOpacity,TouchableHighlight,StyleSheet, Button, View , Text, Pressable} from "react-native";
import props from 'prop-types';


class Tac extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(this.props)
        this.state = {
            text:'',
            disabledbtn:false,

        };
    }


    tonPress = () => {
       console.log(this.props.id);
    };

    render(){
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
            <TouchableOpacity  nativeID='1' id="1"  title='1' style={styles.button} disabled={this.state.disabledbtn} onPress={()=>{this.props.tonPress()}}>
            <Text  nativeID='1' id="1"  title="'title'" style={styles.button} > {this.state.text } 1</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableHighlight id="2" style={styles.button}  disabled={this.state.disabledbtn} onPress={()=>{this.props.tonPress()}}>
            <Text nativeID="2"id="item2" style={styles.button}>  {this.state.text } </Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
            <TouchableHighlight id="3" style={styles.button}  disabled={this.state.disabledbtn} onPress={()=>{this.props.tonPress()}}>
            <Text nativeID="3" id="item3" style={styles.button}> {this.state.text } </Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
```

Comment: do you mean `this.tonPress` ?

Comment: yes i edit  my question

Comment: are you doing `this.props.tonPress` or `this.tonPress`?

Comment: also are you not using something like prettier? it would help a lot with the way your code looks https://prettier.io/

Comment: no i don't use prettier

Comment: this.props.tonPress

Comment: but the props are undefined

Comment: props are never undefined also in your code there is no such prop `tonPress` you have defined that inside the component

Comment: just change `this.props.tonPress` to `this.tonPress` and your code should work

Comment: i have a stupide question, i am new in react native, so nativeID and title are not a props ?

Comment: ok i try to do that, it work but i have an undefined ... why i don't have props in my console

Comment: can you show the code where you pass props?

Comment: i dont have another code only this class

Comment: then you don't have any props. props have to be passed into the component when being rendered from a parent component

Comment: ah ok thank you for your help

Comment: I would recommend reading the official docs https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html